# How do I draw these two lines on a X,Y graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, plot

I don't really know much about drawing graphs on LaTex so I am kind of lost here. One of the lines is y=-3 (a horizontal line at y=-3) and the other is y=x-3.

I have as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
            \begin{figure}[h]
            \foreach \X in {55}
{\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[clip] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw [-latex] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[pos=1.5]{$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[pos=1.5]{$y$};
\path (0,-3) coordinate (X1) (0,-3) coordinate (X2) (3,0) coordinate (X3);
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\shade[ball color=blue] (X\X) circle (2pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}}  
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

I have this so far, but the points are completely off of the graph. Like I said, I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You might look at the TikZ (data visualization) and pgfplots manuals.  There is also pict2e and pstricks, for the nostalgic.

Comment: @BambOo I added what I have so far.

Comment: @BambOo: Please fix your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  so that it compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I guess you addressed your comment to the wrong guy ^^

Comment: @BambOo: Oppsss.. Sorry about that. Luckily the OP still gets notified. though.

Comment: @Peter Grill I made the MWE. Why isn't the output showing?

Comment: @MohammedShahid: First, your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) does not compile. You are missing `\usepackage{tikz}` which is needed before `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`. You are also missing packages necessary to use  `tdplot_main_coords`. But, not sure why you would want to use a 3d library to do a 2d plot. I'd suggest you start with the code give in the answer and work from there to ge the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing plots it is best to use `pgfplots` (built on top of `tikz`):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}% Loaded by pgfplots, so don't need this

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [mark=none, thick, red]  {-3};
    \addplot [mark=none, thick, blue] {x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```